# Java Converting a group of String by replace the speacial characters

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, replace

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "astv*12atthh124ggh*dhr1234sfff123*dgdfg1234*mnaoj";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (m.find()) {
        nums.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
    }
    p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+");
    m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        strings.add(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println(nums);
    System.out.println(strings);
}
```

**Output:**

```
[12, 124, 1234, 123, 1234]
[astv, atthh, ggh, dhr, sfff, dgdfg, mnaoj]
```

But i want output like  :

```
[12124, 1234123, 1234]
[astv, atthhggh, dhrsfff, dgdfg, mnaoj]
```

Comment: Why don't you want `12`, `124`, and `123`? You need to provide some criteria for selection.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Can you explain the logic that you are trying to implement?

Comment: i have a string like "astv*12atthh124ggh*dhr1234sfff123*dgdfg1234*mnaoj", i want to split the numbers and sting separately into an list like this [ astv, atthhggh, dhrsfff, dgdfg, mnaoj]  [12124, 1234123, 1234]

Comment: You need to clarify why `12124` is in the list but `12` is not. Both appear in the string, but only the former is in your list.

Comment: @ManojKumarGovindharaj Yes, that much is clear. What I don't understand is why `12` and `124` should be grouped together, however `124` and `1234` should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep original regex logic, you can do as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "astv*12atthh124ggh*dhr1234sfff123*dgdfg1234*mnaoj";
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern digitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Pattern alphaPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+");
    String[] splittedArray = str.split("\\*");
    for (String nextSplittedString : splittedArray) {
        Matcher digitMatcher = digitPattern.matcher(nextSplittedString);
        Matcher alphaMatcher = alphaPattern.matcher(nextSplittedString);
        String nextDigitAsString = "";
        while (digitMatcher.find()) {
            nextDigitAsString += digitMatcher.group();
        }
        if (!nextDigitAsString.isEmpty()) {
            nums.add(Integer.parseInt(nextDigitAsString));
        }

        String nextString = "";
        while (alphaMatcher.find()) {
            nextString += alphaMatcher.group();
        }
        if (!nextString.isEmpty()) {
            strings.add(nextString);
        }
     }
     System.out.println(nums);
     System.out.println(strings);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[12124, 1234123, 1234]
[astv, atthhggh, dhrsfff, dgdfg, mnaoj]
```

[Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/JR12bX)

Answer (score 2):

You can use split with `*` then you can work with each element for example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "astv*12atthh124ggh*dhr1234sfff123*dgdfg1234*mnaoj";
    String[] spl = str.split("\\*");//[astv, 12atthh124ggh, dhr1234sfff123, dgdfg1234, mnaoj]
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : spl) {

        String tmp = s.replaceAll("\\d+", "");//replace all the digits with empty
        if (!tmp.trim().isEmpty()) {
            strings.add(tmp);
        }

        tmp = s.replaceAll("[a-z]+", "");//replace all the character with empty
        if (!tmp.trim().isEmpty()) {
            nums.add(Integer.parseInt(tmp));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(nums);
    System.out.println(strings);
}
```

---

**Output**

```
[12124, 1234123, 1234]
[astv, atthhggh, dhrsfff, dgdfg, mnaoj]
```

---

## Ideone demo

Comment: without pattern complie initially, need to split with that character right

Answer (score 1):

To get digit array, you can

- replace all alphabets with empty string
- split by asterisk `*`

-
Code

```
String digitArr[] = str.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]", "").split("\\*");
//output
//12124 1234123 1234
```

You can repeat same thing for getting alphabet array

```
String stringArr[] = str.replaceAll("[0-9]", "").split("\\*");
//Output
//astv atthhggh dhrsfff dgdfg mnaoj
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/fNt00y)